# Is it possible to split a value and add an if condition in a LINQ Query?

Tags: c#, json, linq, dictionary, json.net

I am starting with the following JSON response:

```
{
  "d": {
    "RowData": [
      {
        "GenreId": 11,
        "GenreName": "Musical",
        "subjecturl": "subjecturl_123",
        "logourl": "logourl_1"
      },
      {
        "GenreId": 12,
        "GenreName": "kids",
        "subjecturl": "subjecturl_abc",
        "logourl": "logourl_2"
      },
      {
        "GenreId": 13,
        "GenreName": "other",
        "subjecturl": "subjecturl_123",
        "logourl": "logourl_3"
      },
      {
        "GenreId": 14,
        "GenreName": "Musical",
        "subjecturl": "subjecturl_abc",
        "logourl": "logourl_4"
      },
      {
        "GenreId": 15,
        "GenreName": "Music",
        "subjecturl": "subjecturl_123",
        "logourl": "logourl_5"
      },
      {
        "GenreId": 16,
        "GenreName": "Faimaly",
        "subjecturl": "subjecturl_abc",
        "logourl": "logourl_6"
      },
      {
        "GenreId": 17,
        "GenreName": "other",
        "subjecturl": "subjecturl_abc",
        "logourl": "logourl_7"
      },
      {
        "GenreId": 18,
        "GenreName": "other",
        "subjecturl": "subjecturl_123",
        "logourl": "logourl_8"
      },
      {
        "GenreId": 19,
        "GenreName": "kids",
        "subjecturl": "subjecturl_123",
        "logourl": "logourl_9"
      },
      {
        "GenreId": 20,
        "GenreName": "Musical",
        "subjecturl": "subjecturl_123",
        "logourl": "logourl_10"
      },
      {
        "GenreId": 21,
        "GenreName": "other",
        "subjecturl": "subjecturl_123",
        "logourl": "logourl_11"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My goal is to transform the above response into a new response as shown below:

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "title": "Musical",
      "items": [
        {
          "hdsubjecturl": "logourl_123",
          "hdlogourl": "logourl_1",
          "subjecturlsplit": "1"
        },
        {
          "hdsubjecturl": "subjecturl_abc",
          "hdlogourl": "logourl_4",
          "subjecturlsplit": "abc"
        },
        {
          "hdsubjecturl": "logourl_123",
          "hdlogourl": "logourl_10",
          "subjecturlsplit": "10"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "kids",
      "items": [
        {
          "hdsubjecturl": "subjecturl_abc",
          "hdlogourl": "logourl_2",
          "subjecturlsplit": "abc"
        },
        {
          "hdsubjecturl": "logourl_123",
          "hdlogourl": "logourl_9",
          "subjecturlsplit": "9"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Music",
      "items": [
        {
          "hdsubjecturl": "logourl_123",
          "hdlogourl": "logourl_5",
          "subjecturlsplit": "5"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "other",
      "items": [
        {
          "hdsubjecturl": "logourl_123",
          "hdlogourl": "logourl_3",
          "subjecturlsplit": "3"
        },
        {
          "hdsubjecturl": "subjecturl_abc",
          "hdlogourl": "logourl_7",
          "subjecturlsplit": "abc"
        },
        {
          "hdsubjecturl": "logourl_123",
          "hdlogourl": "logourl_8",
          "subjecturlsplit": "8"
        },
        {
          "hdsubjecturl": "logourl_123",
          "hdlogourl": "logourl_11",
          "subjecturlsplit": "11"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Faimaly",
      "items": [
        {
          "hdsubjecturl": "subjecturl_abc",
          "hdlogourl": "logourl_6",
          "subjecturlsplit": "abc"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried the following the LINQ query for making the above response:

```
var data = json["d"]?["RowData"]
    .GroupBy(x => x["GenreName"])
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList())
    .Select(kvp => new
    {
        title = kvp.Key,
        items = kvp.Value.Select(x => new { hdsubjecturl = x["subjecturl"], url = x["logourl"], subjecturlsplit = "" })
    });
var result = JObject.FromObject(new { rows = data });
```

Using this query I made a response like below.

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "title": "Musical",
      "items": [
        {
          "hdsubjecturl": "subjecturl_123",
          "hdlogourl": "logourl_1",
          "subjecturlsplit": ""
        },
        {
          "hdsubjecturl": "subjecturl_abc",
          "hdlogourl": "logourl_4",
          "subjecturlsplit": ""
        },
        {
          "hdsubjecturl": "subjecturl_123",
          "hdlogourl": "logourl_10",
          "subjecturlsplit": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "kids",
      "items": [
        {
          "hdsubjecturl": "subjecturl_abc",
          "hdlogourl": "logourl_2",
          "subjecturlsplit": ""
        },
        {
          "hdsubjecturl": "subjecturl_123",
          "hdlogourl": "logourl_9",
          "subjecturlsplit": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Music",
      "items": [
        {
          "hdsubjecturl": "subjecturl_123",
          "hdlogourl": "logourl_5",
          "subjecturlsplit": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "other",
      "items": [
        {
          "hdsubjecturl": "subjecturl_123",
          "hdlogourl": "logourl_3",
          "subjecturlsplit": ""
        },
        {
          "hdsubjecturl": "subjecturl_abc",
          "hdlogourl": "logourl_7",
          "subjecturlsplit": ""
        },
        {
          "hdsubjecturl": "subjecturl_123",
          "hdlogourl": "logourl_8",
          "subjecturlsplit": ""
        },
        {
          "hdsubjecturl": "subjecturl_123",
          "hdlogourl": "logourl_11",
          "subjecturlsplit": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Faimaly",
      "items": [
        {
          "hdsubjecturl": "subjecturl_abc",
          "hdlogourl": "logourl_6",
          "subjecturlsplit": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Notice that the `subjecturlsplit` is empty for each item.  Here, is it possible to add conditional logic in this LINQ query?  I would like to split the `hdsubjecturl` value on the underscore (`_`) and check whether the second part is equal to `abc`.  If it is, then I want to set `subjecturlsplit` to the `hdsubjecturl` field as it is.  Otherwise, I want to split the `hdlogourl` value on the underscore and set the `subjecturlsplit` to the second part of that split.  Or is there another way to do that?

Comment: Sounds like it, but your question is worded in a convoluted manner. If you are just asking how to write conditional logic in an expression, you can use the ternary operator: `condition ? resultWhenTrue: resultWhenFalse`. Also, since this is LINQ to Objects, your select lambda can have a block body. Basically, you can do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can put a block body in a lambda expression, so you can do your logic there:

```
var data = json["d"]?["RowData"]
    .GroupBy(x => x["GenreName"])
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList())
    .Select(kvp => new
    {
        title = kvp.Key,
        items = kvp.Value.Select(x => 
        {
            var hdsubjecturl = (string)x["subjecturl"];
            var url = (string)x["logourl"];
            var subjecturlsplit = hdsubjecturl.Split('_')[1] == "abc" ? "abc" : url.Split('_')[1];
            return new { hdsubjecturl, url, subjecturlsplit };
        })
    });
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RH60VC

Comment: Thank you for your answer. this is really helpful to me.

Comment: Is It possible to find a Unique value using same Query. It means if logourl same then only store unique logo url in JSON. I tried with .Distinct in every where But no luck