# How to fetch the duplicate data from single field using key pair value in LINQ?

Tags: c#, json, linq, dictionary, json.net

This is my below JSON

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "Response": [{
        "id": 43,
        "Name": "name 1",
        "SubName": "Sub 1"
        "Link": "Link 1",
        "Active": 1,
        "Genre": 8,
        "Description": "Description 1",
        "Languages": "",
        "IsDeleted": 0,
        "GenreId": 8
    },
    {
        "id": 44,
        "Name": "name 1",
        "SubName": "Sub 2"
        "Link": "Link 2",
        "Active": 1,
        "Genre": 9,
        "Description": "Description 2",
        "Languages": "",
        "IsDeleted": 0,
        "GenreId": 9
    },
    {
        "id": 45,
        "Name": "name 1",
        "SubName": "Sub 3"
        "Link": "Link 3",
        "Active": 1,
        "Genre": 10,
        "Description": "Description 3",
        "Languages": "",
        "IsDeleted": 0,
        "GenreId": 10
    },
    {
        "id": 46,
        "Name": "name 2",
        "SubName": ""
        "Link": "Link 4",
        "Active": 1,
        "Genre": 11,
        "Description": "Description 4",
        "Languages": "",
        "IsDeleted": 0,
        "GenreId": 11
    },
    {
        "id": 47,
        "Name": "name 3",
        "SubName": "Sub 1"
        "Link": "Link 5",
        "Active": 1,
        "Genre": 12,
        "Description": "Description 5",
        "Languages": "",
        "IsDeleted": 0,
        "GenreId": 12
    },
    {
        "id": 48,
        "Name": "name 3",
        "SubName": "Sub 2"
        "Link": "Link 6",
        "Active": 1,
        "Genre": 13,
        "Description": "Description 6",
        "Languages": "",
        "IsDeleted": 0,
        "GenreId": 13
    },
    {
        "id": 49,
        "Name": "name 3",
        "SubName": "Sub 3"
        "Link": "Link 7",
        "Active": 1,
        "Genre": 14,
        "Description": "Description 7",
        "Languages": "",
        "IsDeleted": 0,
        "GenreId": 14
    },
    {
        "id": 50,
        "Name": "name 3",
        "SubName": "Sub 4"
        "Link": "Link 8",
        "Active": 1,
        "Genre": 15,
        "Description": "Description 8",
        "Languages": "",
        "IsDeleted": 0,
        "GenreId": 15
    },
    {
        "id": 51,
        "Name": "name 4",
        "SubName": ""
        "Link": "Link 9",
        "Active": 1,
        "Genre": 16,
        "Description": "Description 9",
        "Languages": "",
        "IsDeleted": 0,
        "GenreId": 16
    }]
}
```

and I tried to make like below JSON

```
name 1.json
{
    "rows": [{
        "title": "Sub 1",
        "items": [{
            "id": 43,
            "Name": "name 1",
            "SubName": "Sub 1"
            "Link": "Link 1",
            "Active": 1,
            "Genre": 8,
            "Description": "Description 1",
            "Languages": "",
            "IsDeleted": 0,
            "GenreId": 8
        }]
    },
    {
        "title": "Sub 2",
        "items": [{
            ""id": 44,
            "Name": "name 1",
            "SubName": "Sub 2"
            "Link": "Link 2",
            "Active": 1,
            "Genre": 9,
            "Description": "Description 2",
            "Languages": "",
            "IsDeleted": 0,
            "GenreId": 9
        }]
    },
    {
        "title": "Sub 3",
        "items": [{
            ""id": 45,
            "Name": "name 1",
            "SubName": "Sub 3"
            "Link": "Link 3",
            "Active": 1,
            "Genre": 10
            "Description": "Description 3",
            "Languages": "",
            "IsDeleted": 0,
            "GenreId": 10
        }]
    }
}]
}

name 3.json
{
    "rows": [{
        "title": "Sub 1",
        "items": [{
            "id": 47,
            "Name": "name 3",
            "SubName": "Sub 1"
            "Link": "Link 5",
            "Active": 1,
            "Genre": 12,
            "Description": "Description 5",
            "Languages": "",
            "IsDeleted": 0,
            "GenreId": 12
        }]
    },
    {
        "title": "Sub 2",
        "items": [{
            ""id": 48,
            "Name": "name 3",
            "SubName": "Sub 2"
            "Link": "Link 6",
            "Active": 1,
            "Genre": 13,
            "Description": "Description 6",
            "Languages": "",
            "IsDeleted": 0,
            "GenreId": 13
        }]
    },
    {
        "title": "Sub 3",
        "items": [{
            ""id": 49,
            "Name": "name 3",
            "SubName": "Sub 3"
            "Link": "Link 7",
            "Active": 1,
            "Genre": 14
            "Description": "Description 7",
            "Languages": "",
            "IsDeleted": 0,
            "GenreId": 14
        }]
    },
    {
        "title": "Sub 4",
        "items": [{
            ""id": 50,
            "Name": "name 3",
            "SubName": "Sub 4"
            "Link": "Link 8",
            "Active": 1,
            "Genre": 15
            "Description": "Description 8",
            "Languages": "",
            "IsDeleted": 0,
            "GenreId": 15
        }]
    }
}]
}
```

I'm trying with the duplicate name wise separate a JSON like above. I found only duplicate name and nothing else in JSON.

Does anyone know how to fetch the duplicate value?

I tried with the Linq query and used

```
mygeneratedresponse.Skip(1).ToList();
```

It's working. But is there a better solution?

Comment: *I tried with the Linq queary and apply skip(1). It's Working. But, It's not better solution.* - then please [edit] your question to show what you have tried and explain why "It's not better solution".  From [ask]: *Help others reproduce the problem... if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some.  Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.*

Comment: You have similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63939186/3744182) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63280818/3744182) so if you could reproduce your problem in a minimal fashion we're more likely to be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if is this what you're looking for but, follow a way to get duplicate values grouping it with linq;

you just need to create a consoleapp and add newtonsoft.json to it, to run the code bellow.

```
class Program
    {
        static string pathA = "<place-your-first-json-location-here>"; //ex: c:\test\test.json
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(File.ReadAllText(pathA));

            var filteredByName = json.Response.GroupBy(g => g.Name).OrderBy(o => o.Key).ToList();

            foreach (var item in filteredByName)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Name: {item.Key} Qty response: {item.Count()}" );
            }
        }
    }
```

---

```
public class Test {
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public List<Response> Response { get; set; }
    }

    public class Response {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SubName { get; set; }
        public string Link { get; set; }
        public int Active { get; set; }
        public int Genre { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Languages { get; set; }
        public int IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public int GenreId { get; set; }
    }
```

this is the expected output, so you can go on and apply it to your logic;

```
Name: name 1 Qty response: 3
Name: name 2 Qty response: 1
Name: name 3 Qty response: 4
Name: name 4 Qty response: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code will generate your expected output:
this code is also place at  .net fiddle  https://dotnetfiddle.net/d2uSNC

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var  jsonString = "{    \"status\": \"OK\",    \"Response\": [{        \"id\": 43,        \"Name\": \"name 1\",        \"SubName\": \"Sub 1\",        \"Link\": \"Link 1\",        \"Active\": 1,        \"Genre\": 8,        \"Description\": \"Description 1\",        \"Languages\": \"\",        \"IsDeleted\": 0,        \"GenreId\": 8    },    {        \"id\": 44,        \"Name\": \"name 1\",        \"SubName\": \"Sub 2\",        \"Link\": \"Link 2\",        \"Active\": 1,        \"Genre\": 9,        \"Description\": \"Description 2\",        \"Languages\": \"\",        \"IsDeleted\": 0,        \"GenreId\": 9    },    {        \"id\": 45,        \"Name\": \"name 1\",        \"SubName\": \"Sub 3\",        \"Link\": \"Link 3\",        \"Active\": 1,        \"Genre\": 10,        \"Description\": \"Description 3\",        \"Languages\": \"\",        \"IsDeleted\": 0,        \"GenreId\": 10    },    {        \"id\": 46,        \"Name\": \"name 2\",        \"SubName\": \"\",        \"Link\": \"Link 4\",        \"Active\": 1,        \"Genre\": 11,        \"Description\": \"Description 4\",        \"Languages\": \"\",        \"IsDeleted\": 0,        \"GenreId\": 11    },    {        \"id\": 47,        \"Name\": \"name 3\",        \"SubName\": \"Sub 1\",        \"Link\": \"Link 5\",        \"Active\": 1,        \"Genre\": 12,        \"Description\": \"Description 5\",        \"Languages\": \"\",        \"IsDeleted\": 0,        \"GenreId\": 12    },    {        \"id\": 48,        \"Name\": \"name 3\",        \"SubName\": \"Sub 2\",        \"Link\": \"Link 6\",        \"Active\": 1,        \"Genre\": 13,        \"Description\": \"Description 6\",        \"Languages\": \"\",        \"IsDeleted\": 0,        \"GenreId\": 13    },    {        \"id\": 49,        \"Name\": \"name 3\",        \"SubName\": \"Sub 3\",        \"Link\": \"Link 7\",        \"Active\": 1,        \"Genre\": 14,        \"Description\": \"Description 7\",        \"Languages\": \"\",        \"IsDeleted\": 0,        \"GenreId\": 14    },    {        \"id\": 50,        \"Name\": \"name 3\",        \"SubName\": \"Sub 4\",        \"Link\": \"Link 8\",        \"Active\": 1,        \"Genre\": 15,        \"Description\": \"Description 8\",        \"Languages\": \"\",        \"IsDeleted\": 0,        \"GenreId\": 15    },    {        \"id\": 51,        \"Name\": \"name 4\",        \"SubName\": \"\",        \"Link\": \"Link 9\",        \"Active\": 1,        \"Genre\": 16,        \"Description\": \"Description 9\",        \"Languages\": \"\",        \"IsDeleted\": 0,        \"GenreId\": 16    }]}";
        
         var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString);
        
          var filteredByName = json.Response.GroupBy(g => g.Name).OrderBy(o => o.Key).ToList();

            foreach (var item in filteredByName)
            {
                var fileObject =  item.GroupBy(x=>x.SubName).Select(s=> new { title =s.Key, items= s.ToList()});
               var fileJson =   JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fileObject, Formatting.Indented);
                Console.WriteLine(""  + item.Key +".json");
                Console.WriteLine(fileJson);
                
            }

        
        
    }
}

 public class JsonResponse    {
        public int id { get; set; } 
        public string Name { get; set; } 
        public string SubName { get; set; } 
        public string Link { get; set; } 
        public int Active { get; set; } 
        public int Genre { get; set; } 
        public string Description { get; set; } 
        public string Languages { get; set; } 
        public int IsDeleted { get; set; } 
        public int GenreId { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Root    {
        public string status { get; set; } 
        public List<JsonResponse> Response { get; set; } 
    }
```